# Which parts of a TLS connection can I safely reuse for DTLS to the same peer?

Tags: tls

Suppose I need both encrypted TCP and UDP, say TCP for reliable control signals from server to client and UDP for low latency data from client to server. If I first establish TLS, for the DTLS connection:

- Can I safely skip the certificate verification?
- Is reusing the master secret or sending a new one over the TLS connection more appropriate, or are they both bad?

Comment: In theory, reusing the master secret (assuming you used a proper KDF) is just as secure as sending a new one over the TLS connection and using it as a PSK.